# UnsupportedOperationException when trying to add object to a list and save it in MySQL on Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, set

I'm using Java Spring Boot to create an API.
I'm trying to create a bridge table between two entities: Clients and Users. One client can have multiple users.  My User entity looks like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                "username"
        }),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                "email"
        })
})
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @NaturalId
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

//    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})


    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String username, String email, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

And in the Client entity where I create my bridge table, I'm doing the next:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "empresa")
    private String empresa;
    @Column(name = "telefono")
    private Integer telefono;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Licencia licencia;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_cliente",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public Cliente(String empresa, Integer telefono) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public Integer getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(Integer telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Licencia getLicencia() {
        return licencia;
    }

    public void setLicencia(Licencia licencia) {
        this.licencia = licencia;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

This creates my bridge_table in MySQL using id's as foreign keys. 
Now, when I want to assing a User to a Client, I'm doing the next

```
User user = new User(userModel.getName(), userModel.getUsername(), userModel.getEmail(), userModel.getPassword());
Cliente cliente = clienteRepository.findById(6);
List<User> users = cliente.getUsers();
users.add(user);
cliente.setUsers(users);
clienteRepository.save(cliente);
```

At the moment of save the Client object using the clienteRepository.save() method, it throws me the next exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$1.remove(Collections.java:4712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.clear(AbstractCollection.java:447) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.clear(PersistentSet.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:545) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:923) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:893) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:523) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:418) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:901) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:510) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.pruebas.spring_jdbc.Controllers.UserController.newUser(UserController.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.pruebas.spring_jdbc.Controllers.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$55750dd8.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

Why is this happening? Is something wrong with the way I create the bridge table on the Entity or is something related to the list or the way of saving it in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the list isn't fully initialized as a result of using `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. You're trying to append element to proxy over not fetched list and save that.

You can fix this ugly by setting eager fetching: `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` or use a transaction. Cleaner solution would be to fetch it using for example jpql:

```
select c from Client c left join fetch c.users where id = :id
```

Comment: I tried by changing the fetch type to Eager and it didn't work. What do you mean with the list isn't fully initialized? In this case, the list has one element, and with the new element that I add, there are two elements. If I debbug the app before it saves the Client, the list has two objects inside, but keeps me throwing the same error.

Comment: Is the error thrown with `clienteRepository.save(cliente);` commented?

Comment: Can you paste the whole `User` class in question?

Comment: Could you also paste `Client` class?

Comment: Can you remove cliente.setUsers(users); and try again. You don't need that, because Java actually pass the reference to the object. So, when you users.addUser(user) it updates the client object itself.

Comment: I love you for this answer. Helped me.

Comment: What if I don't want that List to be eagerly loaded? Besides, once the getter-method is called on the lazily loaded relation, shouldn't be loaded than instead of still being proxied?

Comment: @ParrapbanzZ you've got the answer in my post. Leave it as is and it will be loaded in a transaction. But better way is to keep is lazy and use jpql at the end of my answer